# Using scanf for question, allow user to skip question

Tags: c, input, integer, enter

I'm working on a final project for a C programming course. The project is to create a database to store drug information. I've completed all of the elements and now it's down to fine tuning everything.

There's a requirement in the project in the function where the user can change the drugs information. In the requirement, the user should be able to skip a field by hitting enter. For example, the user can change the producer of the drug and the quantity. If the user didn't want to change the producer, they'd hit enter and move onto the quantity.

I've looked around the internet and was able to let the user skip entering a string for the producer. However, I cannot get it work with an integer.

This is what I used so that the user can skip entering a string:

```
scanf("%30[^\n]", fentry[found].producer);
```

For clarity sake, fentry.producer is a string with 30 characters and found is an integer variable.

I've tried doing something similar with the integer input (EDIT: By integer input, I meant the one to enter the quantity, not the 'found' varible). It will let you skip entering something, but if you do enter something, it stores a random value.

Anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `scanf()`, a better way to get interactive input from a user is to use `fgets()`. This function gets a complete line of input up to where the user presses Enter, and returns it so you can parse it.

You can then use `sscanf()` to read the information out of the line, if you like. `sscanf()` works almost exactly like `scanf()` except it reads data from a string rather than from standard input.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got my original problem sorted out.

My programming course is pretty basic compared to what I've stumbled over, so I've never used fgets() or sscanf() before. Is there a way to accept spaces and everything else after one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "allow". The `fgets()` function returns exactly what the user typed, spaces and all, up to a newline where the user pressed Enter. You can either use this string directly (that is, there's no need to use `sscanf()` to get a string from a string), or you can look inside the string if you want to get more than one data item (for example, two numbers on one line).

Comment: It sounds like you're using `sscanf()` to get a string from a string. When you use the `%s` format specifier in `sscanf()`, it stops scanning when it encounters the first whitespace. This is why you only get one word. The answer in this case is to not use `sccanf()` at all, because `fgets()` gives you a complete string itself. All you probably need to do is remove the newline (`'\n'`) off the end.

Comment: your solution works not at all, it the user puts 10 chars with '\n' in your fgets(10chararray,10,stdin), you need extra code to handle this (clear input buffer,extract '\n' from your input-array,...). *scanf with "%s" (or better "%9s") breaks EVER on '\n', you need NEVER extra code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
char s[50];
fgets(s, 50, stdin);

if(s[0] != '\n') {
    fentry[found].producer = atoi(s);
}
```

You have to remove all spaces from s though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the integer to 0 before the scanf?

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%29s", fentry[found].producer); while('\n'!=getchar());
```

This works at all, is strictly ANSI C conform, max. portable.
Input buffer is cleared, chararray-length is supported, chararray contains ever a (terminating) '\0' (no initialization needed) and your array contains never the '\n' from user input.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the keyboard buffer is causing the problems in your code. The first time you call the code, it will read a maximum of 30 characters - so long as they are not the NEWLINE character. They will terminate when they read the NEWLINE. The NEWLINE will remain in the buffer.

However... if you call scanf in the same way again, the NEWLINE from the previous call will still be in the keyboard buffer. This will be read before requesting more input from the keyboard. The NEWLINE will immediately fail the scanf pattern, the char array will not be updated, and you will be left to a char pointer that points to an uninitialized area of memory.